# How do I put an initialValue taken from the useEffect in the textField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I have this edit page where the initial value of the first name, last name, and address should be from the data retrieved from the firebase firestore using the useEffect.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });

        setUsers(arr);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

handleSubmit to save the updated information in the firestore:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
          firstName,
          middleName,
          lastName,
          address,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Below is the entire code:

```
const edit = () => {
  const uid = location.state;
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });

        setUsers(arr);
        setIsLoading(true);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        {isLoading ? (
          <>
            {users &&
              users.map((user) => (
                <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  <CardHeader title="Update Profile" />
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField
                      type="text"
                      value={user.firstName}
                      variant="outlined"
                      label="First Name"
                      fullWidth
                      onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <Button type="submit"> Submit</Button>
                  </form>
                </li>
              ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default edit;
```

Let's say I wanted to edit the address of user "John Park". Those text fields should have the initial value of the first and last names of John so even if the address field was the only one that was updated, the fields first name and last name won't be an empty string when saved in the firestore. How should I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?

Comment: Cant you use useState hook to store the values and change them on input changes then pass them directly in handlesubmit function?

Comment: I sort of agree with @user11823877... you've controlled inputs since using the `value` prop, but I don't see any `onChange` handler.

Comment: @user11823877 what do you mean by this?

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated the code, though there's no output of the firstName when I'll console.log it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are updating the local state, but it isn't initialized to anything but an empty string.

Your updates should be to the local copy of `users` you fetched, and the submit handler should grab a specific user to update in your backend.

```
const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
```

Change handler - curried function to take index and return handler. It maps the previous `users` state to the next, updating the user at the specified index.

```
const changeHandler = index => e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setUsers(users => users.map((user, i) => i === index
    ? {
      ...user,
      [name]: value,
    }
    : user,
  ));
};
```

Submit handler - curried function to take index of specific user object to send to backend.

```
const handleSubmit = index => async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
    const ref = userRef.set(
      { ...users[index] }, // <-- user by index
      { merge: true }
    );
    console.log(" saved");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Pass the current mapped index to the handlers. Add the `name` attribute to each field that matches the user property name for the input.

```
return (
  <div>
    {isLoading ? (
      <>
        {users &&
          users.map((user, index) => (
            <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
              <CardHeader title="Update Profile" />
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(index)}> // <-- pass index
                <TextField
                  type="text"
                  value={user.firstName}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="First Name"
                  name="firstName" // <-- add name attribute
                  fullWidth
                  onChange={changeHandler(index)} // <-- pass index to handler
                />
                ... other fields
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
              </form>
            </li>
          ))}
      </>
    ) : (
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Maybe we can shorten to this: `users[index][name] = value; setUsers([...users])`. Instead of looping using `map`.

Comment: putting the ` onChange={setFirstName(index)}` caused an error that says "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: @Mr_Green Why? You still iterate the data at least once to copy it, and the method you suggest would mutate the state object and this is very anti-pattern in React. It would work if you inverted the steps and did `users[index] = { ...users[index], [name]: value }`. The important part is that `users[index]` is also a new object reference for React.

Comment: @DrewReese oh cool. wasn't aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: @AranyaDream There is no `onChange={setFirstName(index)}` in my answer. In fact, you don't need the extraneous "field" state since you can update the `users` array.

Comment: I think  ```onChange={setFirstName(index)} // <-- pass index```
this needs to be called as ```onChange={() => setFirstName(index)} // <-- pass index```

Comment: @user11823877 The handler is a curried function, but your comment did point me to the fact that I neglected to switch to the correct handler in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AranyaDream Sorry, there was a `onChange={setFirstName(index)}` left in my answer, it should be `onChange={changeHandler(index)}`, so I apologize for any confusion that may've caused.

Comment: @DrewReese ohh alright and it's okay. Thank you